# Migration from Magento to Opencart?

Tags: sql, magento, e-commerce, opencart

I have beeen using magento for my website for last two years,my website has two products and magento is very heavy for my website. i wanted move to opencart ,but i dont know how to export user data base from magento and import to opencart.?
is there any way to do it?

Comment: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=16064